# How to edit a formula that I already have to take into account another cell's data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet that keeps track of bonus for our paralegals. Because we need the clients to be listed in one sheet all the paralegals are also in one sheet instead of each having their own. I need the Excel sheet to add the amount of the bonus for each paralegal individually for which I have the formula:

`=SUM(IF(A2:A35="paralegal1",F2:F35))`.

Now I need to edit this formula so that it takes into account another cell but only when that cell contains data. If that cell does not contain data then I don't want it to add the bonus.

So for example this formula adds the bonus on cells `F2` to `F35` only when `A2` to `A35` show paralegal1. What I need this formula to do is add bonus from cells `F2`-`F35` only when cells `A2`-`A35` show paralegal1 and also cells `E2`-`E35` show data.

So how can I modify the formula to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

if you're using excel 2007 and up, use:

`=sumifs($F$2:$F$35,$A$2:$A$35,"paralegal1",$e$2:$e$25,"<>")`

if you're using 2003 and below, use:

`=sumproduct(($A$2:$A$35="paralegal1")*($e$2:$e$25<>"")*$F$2:$F$35)`